# mvn eclipse:eclipse versus regular maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven

What is the difference between running a maven build on a maven project

```
mvn install
```

then importing the module in eclipse (Import > Existing Maven Projects) as a maven artifact versus running

```
mvn install eclipse:eclipse
```

and importing the maven project as a regular project (Import > Existing Projects into Workspace)?

The second option seems faster within eclipse (mvn install eclipse:eclipse) but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you import an existing Maven project, it is done by [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/), the official Eclipse Maven plugin (when I say official I mean it is in the Eclipse incubation process). It offers more features and can be more convenient to use in my experience

When you do it by `eclipse:eclipse`, it is done by a [Maven Eclipse mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) which creates a simple Java project. The problem is that you have to re-do this again every time you change your `pom.xml`. With *m2e*, this is usually done automatically.

Comment: and when you change your POM, you need to close the project in eclipse (or close eclipse) before running eclipse:eclipse because eclipse itself will overwrite the .project file if it is open.

Comment: @tdrury Hm, I believe a simple refresh (F5) is enough on the project. It will re-read all the `.project` configuration settings.